# Актуальные достоинства и недостатки популярных веб-фрэймворков

Tags: asp.net, django, jsp, asp.net-mvc, ruby-on-rails

Тема создана не для холиваров. Просто необходимо знать какой фрэймворк где использовать и как обосновать свой выбор. Какие недостатки, достоинства есть у конкурентов, независимо от сферы применения (например,  у RoR недостаточно документации по сравнению с .NET). Вобщем вопрос к гуру. Говорить про низкую производительность того же RoR думаю уже давно не актуально, а какие реально весомые отличия (помимо языка и развёртываемого сервера) сказать сложно.

Comment: > (например, у RoR недостаточно документации по сравнению с .NET).

категорически несогласен. Документации море.

Comment: На PHP ещё есть Laravel, малоизвестный у нас.

Answer (score 11):

Опишу свой небольшой опыт.

**Ruby on Rails**

Быстрота разработки, куча готовых гемов, плагинов, море документации статей и т.д. ввиду модности данного фреймворка. Прежде всего годится для быстрого создания сайтов. Начинаем с прототипирования и вперед. Говорят есть проблемы с производительностью. Но говорят, что она обычно упирается в БД, так что довольно спорно. Добавить можно, что Твиттер использует RoR для своих интерфейсов.

**Django**

Это питон. Красивый и гибкий язык. Если бы у меня стояла задача создать сайт, то выбрал бы именно это решение. Почему? Хорошее собщество в том числе на Хабре, много сторонних расширений под любые задачи, мощная стандартная библиотека(побольше рубийной все же). Сказать что Джанга лучше Рельс? Врят ли. Они очень похожи. В Джанго есть админка и классный шаблонизатор, который еще и расширяется. Это очень гибкий фреймворк, так же как и рельсы вропчем. Создан изначально для быстрого создания новостных сайтов и у него это действительно получается хорошо. Есть также плоские страницы.

**РНР(Yii, CodeIgniter)**

Что тут сказать? С него все начиналось. Не думаю что нельзя будет найти какой-то код или компонент для решения задачи в вебе на пхп. Есть все. Единственное что угнетает - это сам язык, хотя изначально я его любил. До знакомства с руби и питоном. Годится как для быстрой разработки, так и для обычной. Зависит от выбранного фреймворка. Yii, например очень классный фреймворк. Похож чем-то на рельсы, но все же отличается многим. Понравился подход к локализации и наличие CRUD-интерфейса для моделей. Важно добавить, что количество вакансий на ПХП значительно больше и это понятно почему, хотя тенденция начинает меняться.

**Grails**

По сути, копия рельс, но для Java. Хотя опять же, не совсем копия. Скорее идеология. Идеология быстрой разработки веб-приложений. Много плагинов, красивый язык, совместимый с Java и самое прикольное - если чего-то нет, то можно взять готовое для Java и адаптировать. Не знаю как сейчас, но в версиях до 1.7 были проблемы с производительностью из-за самого Груви. Но если Груви++ уже адаптировали или включили в ядро груви, то проблема решена. Попробовать в любом случае стоит. Особенно явашникам как я:)

Для крошечных проектов есть минифреймворки(Bootle на питоне, Sinatra на руби). Как правило, для создания сайта из пары динамичных страничек и для быстрого прототипирования например схемы URL-адресов.

Вообще, немного странный вопрос. Обычно либо есть четкое требование от заказчика или команды, либо к чему душа лежит. А так, на любом из фреймворков для популярных языков можно творить самые разные проекты.

Никакого холивара не развожу. Мое личное мнение, так как работал со всеми указанными.

Answer (score 7):

вставлю и свои 5 копеек в пользу **ASP.NET MVC**, хотя до гуру как до луны раком...

- очень удобная работа с JSON благодаря JsonResult, да и вообще работа с клиентским кодом, в частности всякие встроенные "плюшки" с валидацией
- наличие AsyncResult, которые помогают обновлять данные в фоне не блокируя основной поток
- полная поддержка REST, хотя этим уже никого не удивишь
- есть "крутые" контролы от [Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc)
- не стоит забывать про те возможности, которые предоставляет VS при разработке: шаблоны для въюх и контроллеров и прочее
- слышал очень хорошо покрывается тестами, но на своём опыте это не проверял=)
- в отличии от многих продуктов Microsoft, открыта - можно поковырять исходники

в остальном всё на уровне конкурентов. Вообще, если у вас большая часть кода именно на клиенте и нет неприязни к сервеным технологиям Microsoft, то именно этот фреймворк будет наиболее подходящим

Answer (score 5):

в пользу **Django** это админка, если делать простенький проект с нуля, то грубо говоря в два раза меньше времени уйдет

Comment: ASP.NET - также...

Comment: RoR также. Сомнительный критерий

Answer (score 2):

Начнём с того, что пользоваться надо тем, что лучше всего знаешь.
Во - вторых, ещё зависит от того, что собираешься делать.
Приведу пример:
Возьмём за основу два шаблонизатора: **Smarty** и **Twig**.
Цель задания, сделать сайт визитку.
В данном случае, я думаю, использовать какой - то из шаблонизаторов, возможно даже и не имеет смысла. Хотя Twig на пример, очень миниатюрный, но функционал у него весьма даже не мал.
Если надо сделать что - то среднее, можно воспользоваться как **Twig'ом**, так и **Smarty**, тут уже всё зависит от того, чем ты лучше владеешь.
Сделать проект любой сложности можно, в принципе, на любом из этих шаблонизаторов.
Нужно просто определиться, когда и что надо использовать. А когда можно и воздержаться от их использования. )

Так же и c Вашими **.NET** и **RoR**. )

Comment: Ключевое здесь "Начнём с того, что пользоваться надо тем, что лучше всего знаешь" Эта же идея прослеживается в остальном ответе. А потом заказчики будут ругать за то что выбрали "такой то" фрэймворк вместо "такогото". Я же не скажу им что меня в институте научили так программировать а не по другому. Эта идея конечно правильная, но просто очень часто в вакансиях на работу пишут "разработчик должен уметь объяснить бабушке чем один фрэймворк лучше или хуже другого и по каким критериям". И тогда здесь такой ответ уже не прокатит

Comment: Пользователь, как говорится, "по - умлолчанию туп". И его не должно волновать то, на каком фреймворке его сайт. Другое дело интерфейс, которым он пользуется. Если интерфейс, простите, г***о, то там уже не важно, на чём ты делал сайт. Он уже не удобен.  
Другое дело, суметь сделать поправки на уже существующем сайте. Но это уже другой вопрос. :)

Answer (score 2):

В пользу **ASP**:
Для того что бы делать сайты на **ASP.NET**, нужно знать на базовом уровне **HTML** и **VB.NET**, ещё у **ASP** есть **MVC**, также как и у **RoR**, но **ASP** проще тем, что у него есть **IDE**, от разработчиков фреймворка с визуальным редактором...

Comment: текст как будто сеошники писали

Comment: Ха, спасибо, хотя я.SEO = 0 'Прям на VB написал XD

Comment: не обнаружил в ответе ни преимуществ, ни недостатков. По поводу IDE с WYSIWYG - мне кажется в VS это скорее недостаток, точно также как редактор интерфейса android в eclipse

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET webforms - высокая абстрактность.